# How to use a programmatic 'get' equivalent in a WPF dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, getter

Where this is the clr way of writing a property:

```
public byte Value
{
   get{
     return GetByteData();
   }
   set{
     SetByteData(value);
   }
}
```

I've read up on how to do the same the dependency property way, and this is all I could do by myself:

```
public byte Value
{
    get { return (byte)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Value", typeof(byte), typeof(MyControl),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata((byte)0, ValueChanged));

public static void ValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    byte r = (byte)e.NewValue;
    MyControl v = (MyControl)d;
    v.SetByteData(r);
}
```

With the examples I've looked at, from which I've made the above snippet, I can't find a place to put the `GetByteData()`, which calculates an output value for the current UI-state when the user interacts, so as to update the 'Value'.

Until previously I was putting it in the getter anyway like with clr, but I get the feeling that it's the wrong approach, but I could be wrong. Where should I be putting it? If not, what should be my approach? Is it at all possible to have a programmatic getter for a dependency property?

It's possible that I've been using the wrong keywords to look for a solution. Any help putting me in the right direction would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, dependency properties don't have a "get callback". Their getter always and only returns the value that was previously set (either directly, or by a Binding, Style, default value, etc). Why does your property have to be a dependency property at all?

Comment: Note also that the assignment `v.Value = r` in the PropertyChangedCallback is redundant. The property already has that value. I have removed it from your sample code.

Comment: Oh! A different approach entirely! So that means I have to update the dependency value by firing an event whenever the user interacts? I suppose that would use `SetByteData` everytime to sync the UI. Kind of redundant but I guess I could use a state-variable to make it skip the redoing. @why it needs to be dependency: I need a different UI element to do: `{Binding Value, ElementName=MyControlName}`. I'm not sure if this would work with clr properties...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it is only the source (and not the target) property of a Binding, as in

```
{Binding Value, ElementName=MyControlName}
```

and you don't want to apply a value by a Style Setter, or animate the value, the property does not need to be a dependency property.

Just implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` like this:

```
public partial class MyControl : UserControl, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public byte Value
    {
       get { return GetByteData(); }
       set
       {
           SetByteData(value);
           PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
       }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: I will perhaps require it as target as well, eventually. But I haven't found a place to implement it in that way yet. It's actually a control that shows a 'byte' with a series of togglebuttons that represent individual bits. And a section for manually typing the number as well, within the same user-control. So, it's sort of a library control I intend to use at a lot of places. Having a dependency property might be helpful. I'll try updating the dependency value everytime the user interacts with my control, and see how that works out.

Comment: Also, thanks for the `PropertyChanged?.Invoke` syntax. I was wondering how to make that work, since I'm used to the C++ way of just doing `PropertyChanged(this, new ...);`

Comment: Thanks for the guidance. I managed to get it working.  Just write that wpf getters don't work like that or that i have to update it manually. I'll mark it as answer as that would be most relevant to the question. :)